# Decorating pyramid views implemented as class methods

Tags: python, metaprogramming, pyramid

I have code like this in my pyramid project:

```
class SomeViews(object):

    @view_config(...)
    def view_a(request):
       return {...}

    @view_config(...)
    def view_b(request):
       return {...}
```

I would like to decorate the view methods to modify the returned dictionary. It's possible to apply an decorator to a view, if it's the first one before `view_config`. Otherwise Pyramid is still using the original function, due to the nature of Venusian.

Because I would apply the same decorator to all methods in a class, I would prefer to use a class decorator. So instead of doing

```
    @view_config(...)
    @my_decorator("some_meta_info")
    def view_b(request):
       return {...}
```

for each method, I would like to do

```
@my_decorator("some_meta_info")
class SomeViews(object):
    ...
```

But because the class decorator is executed after the `view_config` calls, again it does not work with Venusian. I had a look at the `view_defaults` implementation, to get a hint how to solve my problem, but I did not figured out how it works.

Any hint how to do that? What I want to do, is just to modify the result dictionary of a set of view methods. I also thought about using the `BeforeRender` event, but I found no way to inject the required meta data in a way that I can access it in the event handler. Using decorators would anyway be the more natural and pythonic way in my opinion.

Comment: Your views should accept `self` (the class instance), not `request`. The request object is passed into the `__init__`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import functools

def my_decorator(value):
    def _dec(f):
        @functools.wraps(f)
        def wrapper(context, request):
            print 'hey look!', value
            return f(context, request)
        return wrapper
    return _dec

@view_defaults(decorator=my_decorator('some meta info'))
class SomeViews(object):
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request

    @view_config(..., renderer='string')
    def view_a(self):
        return 'foo'
```

Think of `view_defaults` as default options passed to every `view_config` on the class. If you add a decorator to the `view_config` though, the defaults are overridden and your default decorator would be dropped.

Comment: Great answer! Question about this - is there a way to use view_defaults so I can add arguments to my views?

For example, in function-based views, I sometimes use decorators to parse GET parameters and call my view with something like my_view(request, params).

Comment: This is possible using a view mapper, it's different from the "decorator" argument in pyramid. The most comprehensive one floating around is probably the one in the pyramid_rpc repository, they are not trivial to write if you want them to work on class methods, functions, etc. See https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid_rpc/blob/master/pyramid_rpc/mapper.py. However if you have one for a specific set of views it'll be much easier!